# IE<= 10: I can type characters inside contenteditable=false element

Tags: contenteditable

This is my DOM structure:

```html
<div contentediatble="true">
  <span contenteditable="false" class="my-block">
    <span contenteditable="false">My Block</span>
    <i contenteditable="false" class="icon-remove">X</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

The root `<div>`looks like a textbox:

In IE 9 and 10, when I click the root `<div>`, suppose my caret will after the `<span class="my-block">` element, and when I typing, the words should be after the whole block.

But actually, when I start typing, the characters is actually INSIDE the `<span class="my-block">` element(rather than AFTER), followed by the `<i contenteditable="false" class="icon-remove">X</i>`, and I can even delete the contents of `<span class="my-block">` by using backspace(but not delete the whole span)

This is so annoying and it's really hard to fix. IE really makes tons of troubles to developers :(

However, the expected result works well in FF, Chrome and IE11.

Comment: `contentediatble`? I assume that's a transcription error in the div, yes?

Comment: Oh, sorry, a typo, it's "contenteditable", thanks for reminding!